# UITextField becomeFirstResponder works only once

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

In my app, there is the ability for the user to input their name.

A UITextField is added to the view and becomeFirstResponder is called.
In the textFieldShouldReturn method, resignFirstResponder is called.
Then in textFieldShouldEndEditing, the UITextField is removed from the view.

This all works fine, but the problem is that when the user tries to input their name a second time, the UITextField shows but keyboard does not.

I have tried lots of things, like moving around become/resign firstresponder or retaining/not retaining the textfield, but I just cant seem to get it to work.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [textField becomeFirstResponder]; Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: maybe just hide the text field instead of removing it from the view?

Comment: Why do you and and remove the textfield at all!? Please show some code and describe your view structure.

Comment: @user1270338 Put your code So that we can understand, what you are doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property set for that UITextField, make sure to set it to nil after removing it from the view.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the work in textFieldDidEndEditing, and when you tap on text field second time,  control should go in textFieldShouldBeginEditing, try checking that with break points, it it does not goes then problem is that your textfield does not have any memory allocated and if it goes in this function set this textfield as first responder.

Comment: or you can do one thing more do not resign it.. on should end editing, resign it afterwards in some other call back function. it will work for u.